# Dart (Flutter) Wrong Time Zone- GMT is set as GMT 0 although my time zone is GMT +1. How can I change it?

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart, timezone, gmt

Code:
DateTime date = DateTime.now();
print(date.timeZoneName);

Result : I/flutter (18415): GMT

The Result should be GMT +1

Thanks

Comment: The timezone information should come from your device itself. Are you sure you have setup the correct timezone in the device's time and clock settings?

Comment: yes, the Emulator time zone was not correct. Thank you for the quick reply.

Comment: Great, I have posted an answer you can accept. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timezone used by Dart (and Flutter) when using localtime is coming from the OS on the device the application is running on. So if the timezone does match an expected timezone, please check the timezone settings on your device and verify they match your expectation.